# Rspec and Capybara: saving results to database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, database-cleaner

I'm fairly new to RSpec and have been trying to create some tests for my website, on which a user can post a reservation to the website, which is then saved to our database. I've been trying, using Rspec and Capybara, to simulate a user posting a reservation to the website. We have an existing test database, and at the end of the Rspec test want the new reservation to be written to the database, and *not* removed at the end of the Rspec test.

One of two things happens when we run the code: either it "works" but the new reservation can't be found in the database, or we get this error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   Mysql2::Error: This connection is in use by: #<Thread:0x007fb421fd6218 sleep>: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 6  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 # ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:95:in `pass_login_status_to_js'
 # ./app/middleware/search_suggestions.rb:12:in `call'
```

Why would this be happening? I realize that Capybara isn't generally meant to be making permanent changes to a database; is there a different program/gem you recommend?

I currently have `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`, and also have added the following on the recommendation of a few websites:
    class ActiveRecord::Base
      mattr_accessor :shared_connection
      @@shared_connection = nil

```
  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

To reiterate, I *do* want Capybara to be writing to my database (we use SQL). What can I do differently? Does it have something to do with database cleaner?

Comment: database_cleaner, as the name indicates cleans up the database after test runs. Exactly how depends on how you have configured it.

Comment: Why do you want to leave data in your database at the end of a test run?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has everything to do with `database_cleaner`. If you have it setup properly, it will clean your database between scenarios, to keep the tests isolated.

There are a few ways to do what you want:

1. You can explicitly tell `database_cleaner` not to clean certain tables between scenarios:

   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction, {except: [:countries, :states]}
   DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, {except: [:countries, :states]})
2. You can add your code to a `before(:each)` or `before(:all)` block
3. You can add your data to one or many fixtures

There are only a few cases where you should share data between scenarios (ie. countries, states tables, which are good candidates for #3)

In any other case, I advise against sharing data between scenarios.